# How to access specific pixels (part) of image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

How can i access only the pixels of specific part of the image ? Is there any proper method of accessing those or i need to use `hit and trial` method for it . 
For example i want to access all the pixels within the circle `( this circle is just draw for understanding)` will not have it in real problem.

[image]

I want to access only these pixels for changing values , one way which just come to mind is

getting the four corners of image

```
vector<Point> corners(4);
corners[0] = Point(0, 0);
corners[1] = Point(my_img.width, 0);
corners[2] = Point(0, my_img.height);
corners[3] = Point(my_img.width, my_img.height);
```

then find its center

```
Point center = Point(my_img.size().width/2, my_img.size().height/2);
```

make radius

```
double radius = 2.0;
```

and then put new values inside of radius or circle

```
image.at<cv::Vec3b>(row,col)[0] = newval[0];  //B
image.at<cv::Vec3b>(row,col)[1] = newval[1];  //G
image.at<cv::Vec3b>(row,col)[2] = newval[2];  //R
```

but then how to access pixels inside it (need solution which work for all images not only for this specific) , or `any other logic or idea is appriciated`

Comment: Can't you just iterate over the entire image and test whether the distance from the center of the circle to the current pixel is smaller than the radius?